# Updating Incremental value to a column in a SQL table for a group of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where I have to update a incremental value to a column based on the value on the same column from the previous row for the same group of records.

[image: Initial Table]

Rule for updating 'COUNT' column is:

```
For the very 1st row of a particular REFNO, 
If Amount 1 = Amount 2 then 
   COUNT = 1 
Else 
   COUNT = 0
```

**For all other rows (excluding the 1st row) of a particular REFNO:**

```
If Amount 1 = Amount 2 then
   COUNT = COUNT from previous row for the same REFNO + 1
Else  
   COUNT = COUNT from previous row for the same REFNO
```

So the result should look like below:

[image: After Update]

Though the sample data which I have shown has only 14 records the actual table I am updating is going to have few million rows in them. So I am searching for a solution which will do a set based update rather than row by row processing !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update from a CTE that uses [window functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/) to calculate the number.

The SQL below first calculates a row_number for the equal amounts.
Then for the others that don't have an equal amount, the maximum of the previous row_number is taken.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, 
    (CASE 
     WHEN [Amount 1] = [Amount 2] 
     THEN rn 
     ELSE MAX(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY [REFNO] ORDER BY [ROW ID] ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
     END) as rnk
    FROM (
      SELECT 
       [ROW ID], [REFNO], [Amount 1], [Amount 2], [COUNT],
       (CASE 
        WHEN [Amount 1] = [Amount 2] 
        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [REFNO], IIF([Amount 1] = [Amount 2],0,1) ORDER BY [ROW ID] ASC) 
        ELSE 0 
        END) AS rn
      FROM PAYMENT
    ) q
)
UPDATE CTE
SET [COUNT] = rnk;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=114308aa4efdd414434dc51264332961)*

Comment: Hi LukStorms.. Thanks very much for the solution !! This works well for the smaller set as well as the larger set which I had !!! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Try it's

```
declare @t table (
    rowid int identity,
    refno int,
    amount1 int,
    amount2 int

)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000000,100,200)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000000,250,250)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000000,300,300)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000000,400,400)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000010,400,100)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000010,200,100)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000010,100,300)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000021,400,400)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000021,200,100)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000032,200,200)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000032,300,300)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000033,200,100)
insert into @t(refno,amount1,amount2) values (1000033,200,100)

select rowid,refno,amount1,amount2,rw-1 as count
from (
select
    row_number() over(partition by amount1,amount2 order by rowid) rw,*
from @t) as src
```

Comment: Nope, the results don't look like what the OP is seeking. How does this keep separate counts for each value of `RefNo`?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for that particular set, but no guarantee that there will be a situation when it won't work:

```
CREATE TABLE  #tmp(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    RefNo INT,
    Amount1 INT,
    Amount2 INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmp(RefNo,Amount1,Amount2) 
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(100000,100,200),
(100000,250,250),
(100000,300,300),
(100000,400,400),
(100000,400,100),
(100010,200,100),
(100010,100,300),
(100010,400,400),
(100021,200,100),
(100021,200,200),
(100032,300,300),
(100032,200,100),
(100033,200,100),
(100033,200,100)) AS x(a,b,c)

;WITH Try1 AS (SELECT t1.*, [Count] = 
            CASE WHEN t1.Amount1 != t1.Amount2 AND 
                (t2.RowId IS NULL OR t2.Amount1 != t2.Amount2) THEN 0 
                WHEN t1.Amount1 != t1.Amount2 AND t2.Amount1 = t2.Amount2 THEN t2.RowId
                WHEN t1.Amount1 = t1.Amount2 AND t2.RowId IS NULL THEN t1.RowId
                WHEN t1.Amount1 = t1.Amount2 AND t2.RowId IS NOT NULL THEN t1.RowId 
            END
            , NextRefNo = CASE WHEN t2.RowId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM #tmp AS t1
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT * FROM #tmp AS t2 
        WHERE t2.RowId = t1.RowID - 1 AND t2.RefNo = t1.RefNo) AS t2)
, Try2 AS (SELECT RowID, RefNo, Amount1, Amount2, [Count]
                , NextRefNo = ISNULL(t2.NextRefNo,0)
            FROM Try1 AS t1
            OUTER APPLY ( SELECT NextRefNo FROM Try1 AS t2 
                WHERE t2.[Count] > 0 AND t2.NextRefNo = 1 
                    AND t2.RefNo = t1.RefNo ) AS t2)
SELECT RowID, RefNo, Amount1, Amount2
    , [Count] = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY RefNo ORDER BY [Count]) - 1 + NextRefNo
FROM Try2
ORDER BY RowID;
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks very much for your time and solution !! I will try this out for the larger set to see if it fits in !!!

Comment: I think LukStorms provided more elegant solution.